# Why is copying an unordered map slow in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm writing code on a ARM cortex A9 for a real time robotics application. I'm experiencing some timing issues with my interrupts. I am copying a global variable into the interrupt which takes 20us on an interrupt at 20kHz. That leaves me about 40us for the idle.. Just copying takes 20us!

So my question is why copying an unordered map into another unordered map take so much time?

```
class Supervisor {
private:
    DispatchCommunication dispatchComm;
    DispatchLogic dispatchLogic;

    std::unordered_map<std::string, uint32_t> fetchedData;
public:
    void initialize(void);
    void communication(void);
    void logic(void);
};

inline void Supervisor::initialize(void) {
    dispatchComm.initialize();

    dispatchLogic.initialize();    
}

/**
 * Get all sensor data
 */
inline void Supervisor::communication(void) {

    // Create a map of the data we want to request from the communication dispatcher
    std::vector<std::string> requestMap = { "jointAngle", "motorAngle", "piggyback" };

    // Fetch the requested data
    fetchedData = dispatchComm.getDataVector(requestMap);


}

/**
 * Run all the logic
 */
inline void Supervisor::logic(void) {

    std::unordered_map<std::string, uint32_t> IRQFetchedData;

    // This part takes a whopping 20us!
    IRQFetchedData = fetchedData;

}
```

Comment: It's a node-based container, so you are taking many, many trips to the heap.

Comment: Without knowing the size of the map, the speed of the processor and the compiler version+options, it is difficult to tell if 20us is fast, slow or expected. Depending on your compiler and compiler options it could take tens of cycles to copy each element. At 1GHz, 20us is 20K cycles and could be the expected timing to a few hundred elements

Comment: Do you have to copy or could you perhaps move?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, it's not just the copying of the map. It's the copying of the `std::string`s within the map. That means (potentially) lots of memory allocations. And even without those allocations (small-string optimization), it's still lots of copying of string data.

And that's all on top of the copying needed for the map itself, which involves its own series of allocations, based on bucket sizes, the various heap implementation strategies, etc.

If fast copying is something you need, then perhaps a sorted `vector` would be more appropriate, rather than an `unordered_map`. That won't help the `string` copying issue, but it can help the cost of copying the map itself. You can even speed that up by using a fixed-length string class, which could be trivially copyable. That could make copying the entire `vector` a single memory allocation followed by a single `memcpy`.

Of course, it is (theoretically) slower to access a value from a sorted `vector` than an `unordered_map`. But that's the give-and-take when it comes to performance. Fast copying or fast access; which matters to you? Though even fast access is theoretical, primarily mattering when such maps are *large*.

Comment: Mentioning that strings were slowing it down made me realize I only used strings for readability. I can just use defines mapped to hex values.

Comment: @Ortix92 There are enums if you don't want to compromise on readability and performance. Chances are your IDE will show the enum name when you debug, instead of its value

Comment: @Ortix92 in that case, use enums as suggested above, and to avoid all the inefficiencies of the maps, use a vector. If your enum is "`struct Request {enum {K0=0, K1, K2, SIZE} Key;};`", you would create "`std::vector<uint32_t> fetchedData(Request::SIZE)`" and access the elements as in `fetchedData[K1]`